# How to install package 'coin' in R 3.1.3

Tags: r, installation, package

I am using R 3.1.3 and I need to install the package `coin` to be able to extract z values from the outout of the wilcoxon test, as explained [here](http://yatani.jp/teaching/doku.php?id=hcistats:wilcoxonsigned).

I tried installing the `coin` library, but I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [coin.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘coin’
* removing ‘/home/hlabbeg1/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/coin’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘coin’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried installing the packages `lblas` and `lgfortran` but in both cases I get a message saying the packages are not available for R version 3.1.3. I couldn't even find them on the cran repositories.

Trying to install the package directly gives me the following error:

```
Error in rawToChar(block[seq_len(ns)]) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\n\0\0\0\0\0\xb1\004\x8fF\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\005\0\0\0coin/PK\003\004\024\0\002\0\b\0\xae\004\x8fF\xce\xe2\x91\xcb6\002\0\0:\006\0\0\r\0\0\0coin/CITATION\xad\x93Qo\xda0\020ǟɧ8\xf9)Hi\xa0\xa0\xb1\b\xa9\017'
```

Any idea oh how to install these packages so I can get `coin`?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to have `blas` and `gfortran` installed on your Linux.

Comment: Hi @Pascal . I was able to figure that out from the error message. As I said, I tried to install blas (and lblas) and lgfortran but every time I got the message saying they were not available for version of R 3.1.3.

Comment: If you carefully read my comment, I speak about **Linux**, not **R**. [blas](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) and [gfortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran) are Linux libraries.

Comment: You were right @Pascal . I didn't thought I could be missing general linux libraries. It was a bit hard to find the blass package, which in my repositories had a different name. At the end I installed both and was then able to install `coin` simply with the `install.packages()` function.